# How can I calculate height and width of a rectangle when I scale it in a rectangle class?

Tags: android, drawing, zooming, gesturedetector

How can i calculate height and width of a rectangle when I scale it in a rectangle class ?

This is my class rectangle what can I add inside the scale method to change sizes ? Thanks.

I did some edit on the code: 
    public class Rectangle extends Graphic{

```
public Rectangle(float centerX, float centerY, float width, float height) {
    super(centerX, centerY, width, height);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float left = getCenterX() - (getWidth()*getScaleX())/2 ;
    float top = getCenterY() - (getHeight()*getScaleY())/2 ;
    float right = getCenterX() + (getWidth()*getScaleX())/2 ;
    float bottom = getCenterY() + (getHeight()*getScaleY())/2 ;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1.0f);
        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
}

@Override
protected void onScale(float scaleFactorX, float scaleFactorY, float focusX, float focusY) {
    float newWidth = getWidth()*scaleFactorX;
    float newHeight = getHeight()*scaleFactorY;
    setWidth(newWidth);
    setHeight(newHeight);
}

@Override
protected void onDrag(float dx, float dy) {

}

@Override
protected void onSelectChange(boolean selected) {

    if (selected)
        getPaint().setColor(Color.GRAY);

}

@Override
protected void onClickEvent(float x, float y) {
    float left = getCenterX() - (getWidth()*getScaleX())/2 ;
    float top = getCenterY() - (getHeight()*getScaleY())/2 ;
    float right = getCenterX() + (getWidth()*getScaleX())/2 ;
    float bottom = getCenterY() + (getHeight()*getScaleY())/2 ;

    if(x > left && x < right && y > top && y < bottom)
        setSelected(true);
    else
        setSelected(false);
}

@Override
protected void onLongPressEvent(float x, float y) {

}

@Override
protected void onRotate(double angle) {

}
}
```

Comment: ... multiply the old sizes by the new scale?

Comment: Yes, how can i do it inside that class above ?

Comment: Your class looks like it's missing some important bits.

Comment: I did like that. Is it correct ?

Comment: float newWidth = getWidth()*scaleFactorX;
        float newHeight = getHeight()*scaleFactorY;
        setWidth(newWidth);
        setHeight(newHeight);

Comment: Looks correct, to me.